# How to get json values from path inside vs code extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

Tried to get json values using below code but not working.This code is not working only inside my visual studio code extension: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension
I do not know why it is not working inside vscode extension.Anyone can find the solution?

```
var file = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("c:\\xampp\\htdocs\\projects\\chemis\\package.json", "utf8"));
vscode.window.showInformationMessage(file);
```

Comment: For json file you can just do ```const fileData = require("c:\\xampp\\htdocs\\projects\\chemis\\package.json")```

Comment: Tried but not working..getting [Object Object]

Comment: try doing ```JSON.stringify(fileData)``` if you will print JSON with console log it will print [Object Object].

Comment: I think some other format is there inside visual studio code extension.js

Answer (score 0):

The reason the original code does not work is you are passing the result of [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), which is an object, to [window.showInformationMessage](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window), which expects a string.  In that situation, showInformationMessage silently does nothing.

To fix that, pass a string instead.  As Arshad suggested, [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) is one way to do that.

In a comment, you mentioned getting "[object Object]".  That is what happens if you stringify by calling [Object.prototype.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) or by concatenating with a string (which implicitly calls toString).